# Is it possible to fill with values above plus filtering the table, with one formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with columns named "groups", "subgroups", "specifics" as well as values across the 12 months. I want to (1) fill first two columns with the values above and (2) sort this table to only specifics. Is there a formula to do it?

**Given Data**

| group | sub | spec | sum | mon1 | mon2 | mon3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a |  |  |  | 3 | 3 | 3 |
|  | b |  |  | 2 | 3 | 3 |
|  |  | c | 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
|  |  | c1 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
|  | b1 |  |  | 3 | 4 | 5 |
|  |  | c2 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| a1 |  |  |  | 5 | 5 | 5 |
|  | b2 |  |  | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|  |  | c3 | 9 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|  |  | c4 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
|  |  | c5 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

**Desired Output**

| group | sub | spec | sum | mon1 | mon2 | mon3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| a | b | c1 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| a | b1 | c2 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| a1 | b2 | c3 | 9 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| a1 | b2 | c4 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| a1 | b2 | c5 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>SCAN( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A12,
     b,B2:B12,
     c,C2:G12,
     d,SCAN("",a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     e,SCAN("",b,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     VSTACK(A1:G1,SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(d,e,c),INDEX(c,,1)<>0),3)))
```

---

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly with given example. I forgot to say that "sum" and following columns aren't blanks, they are also filled with values, but I need only values with rows in specifics. What would be different in this case?

Comment: Interesting: Although `INDEX(c,,1)` on its own returns zeros instead of blanks, you can still use the more accurate `INDEX(c,,1)<>""`. Otherwise, if there are *Nothings* (="") in the *spec* column, they will also show.

Comment: Nice use of SCAN. I would expect it to work without the use of index (`c<>""`), but it doesn't. Why do we need to use INDEX here?

Comment: All works thanks @VBasic2008 Sir, thanks P.b. OP initially had some different data, at that i tried using `INDEX(c,,1)<>""` it wasnt working on my end so i had to use the `0` but with the present update it `INDEX(c,,1)<>""` works however i kept the use of `INDEX(c,,1)<>0`, in excel i found `0` and `""` makes no difference also i can use `TAKE()` or `DROP()`